# Read datasets one by one and put them next to the previous plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have some datasets which are too big and I want to plot these datasets with `matplotlib`'s `imshow()` function.

I need to plot the datasets concatenated with `matplotlib`, but since the datasets are quite large, when I try to concatenate it causes my computer to overheat (I use the `NumPy` library to concatenate). Is it possible for me to read these datasets one by one and put them next to the previous plot, as I have given below as a gif? Since I read all datasets one by one, it will not cause heating.

[image]

Comment: Imshow has an “extent” keyword argument that allows you to put the image where you want on the x axis.

Comment: But I couldn't find a way to do this with extend.

Comment: What did you try?  Suggest updating your question with complete reproducible code that is as minimal as possible.

Comment: Also you could see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html

Comment: @mehmet_kacmaz_03 can you give feedback on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68557124/16343464), I am curious to know if it solved your problem, and if the computer managed to produce the plot

Comment: Thank you. It helped me too much but I have a new problem. Here is just an array named array. What should I do if I have two different arrays and plot them as subplots (subplot(211) and subplot(212))? I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume this input:

```
array = np.diag(np.ones(3))
arrays = [array,array*2,array*3]
```

```
[array([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]),
 array([[2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 2.]]),
 array([[3., 0., 0.],
        [0., 3., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]])]
```

looking like:

```
plt.imshow(np.concatenate(arrays, axis=1))
```

[image: original data]

Now we want to plot block by block. For this we loop over the blocks and use the `extent` option of [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html)

```
ax = plt.subplot()

vmin = min(a.min() for a in arrays)  ## if you know the values in advance you
vmax = max(a.max() for a in arrays)  ## can input them instead of calculating

for i,a in enumerate(arrays):
    h,w = a.shape
    ax.imshow(a, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
              extent=[(w*i)-0.5, (w*(i+1))-0.5, h-0.5, -0.5])
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, (w*(i+1))-0.5)
```

[image: imshow block by block]

You need to know in advance the min/max values of your whole dataset and specify it to `imshow` with the `vmin`/`vmax` parameters, otherwise each dataset will be scaled independently.

Now, if the arrays have different widths (`arrays = [array,(array*2)[:, :2],array*3]`), you can use the following:

```
ax = plt.subplot()

vmin = min(a.min() for a in arrays)
vmax = max(a.max() for a in arrays)

W = 0
for i,a in enumerate(arrays):
    h,w = a.shape
    ax.imshow(a, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
              extent=[W-0.5, (W+w)-0.5, h-0.5, -0.5])
    W+=w
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, W-0.5)
```

[image: imshow blocks of different width]